# Как изменить внешний вид поля формы?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, как вместо прямоугольного стандартного поля формы получить поле в виде длинного нижнего подчеркивания?

Answer (score 3):

Так будет просто линия.

```css
input{
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  outline: 0;  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: тоже верно. Вообще input - вещь такая что у каждого браузера она будет реагировать по своему.

Comment: убирать `outline`, без добавления каких-то других стилей при фокусе, у элементов, которые есть в дереве доступности, это плохая идея.

Answer (score 2):

```css
input {
  border:0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 2):

может так:

```css
input{
border:0 solid #fff;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: border:0 solid #fff; - а смысл в этой части кода, если border-bottom говорит сразу о том, что для все остальных сторон мы отключаем линию?

Comment: @Юрий кому говорит? запустите свой код в примере и уведите, что не всем говорит... ))

Comment: @Юрий вот: https://jsfiddle.net/pr6tpawo/

Comment: просто указание цвета лишнее у вас, зачем ставить цвет если вы убираете border, как и указание solid - тоже лишнее. правильно будет в таком случае: input{
border:0 ;
border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}

Comment: @Юрий это  да... "привычка, плохой помощник"..)) все верно, хватит только 0.